# Why is reallocation in my program not working properly?

Tags: c

I want to make a program that stores inputed words into a 2D array (it can be as many as you want) and once you input word 'END', program should get out of the while loop. But for now user can input max. 5 words, and once he do that, program should reallocate 2d array with more rows. But there's something wrong with reallocation and I dont know what.

Here's a code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 20

char** allocate(int n, int m) {
    char** arr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * m);
    return arr;
}
void printList(char** polje, int n, int m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", polje[i]);
    }
}
int main() {
    int n = 5;
    int index = 0;
    char** list = allocate(5,MAX);
    char input[MAX];

    while (strcmp("END", input)) {
        scanf(" %s", input);

        if (index % 5 == 0) {
            n += 5;
            list = (char**)realloc(list, sizeof(char*) * n);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                list[i] = (char*)realloc(list[i], sizeof(char) * MAX);
        }

        if (strcmp("END", input) != 0) {
            strcpy(list[index], input);
            index++;
        }
    }

    printList(list, index, MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your intent is to allocate an n x m array-of-arrays (well, array of pointers to arrays), but `allocate` uses `n` for both dimensions, with `m` being unused.  That seems like a bug.

Comment: Yup, but it still doesnt change the fact that reallocation is not working properly

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `realloc` is being called with an invalid pointer.

After:

```
            n += 5;
            list = (char**)realloc(list, sizeof(char*) * n);
```

`list[n - 5]`, `list[n - 4]`, `list[n - 3]`, `list[n - 2]`, and `list[n - 1]` contain invalid pointer values.  So in the subsequent:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                list[i] = (char*)realloc(list[i], sizeof(char) * MAX);
```

The `realloc` is being passed invalid pointers when `i` is in the range `n - 5` to `n - 1`.